# git log after moving file to separate branch

Tags: git, git-mv

I've moved a bunch of files to a separate branch, to avoid mixing separate histories. Then I moved the files on the new branch to `/` (so that they can be checked out in a worktree rooted exactly where they were initially located):

```
git branch -c scripts
git rm -rf scripts/
git commit -m 'scripts -> new branch'
git switch scripts
# git rm -rf files NOT under scripts/
git mv scripts/* .
git commit -m "scripts -> top level of new branch
```

Now, of course, while *new* history looks clean on both branches, I'm having trouble viewing *past* history. `git log --follow` expects a single file name.

On the main branch, I can

- `xargs -0 -a <(git ls-files -z) git log --` (get log for existing files)

On the scripts `branch`, it's not so simple; I think I need to either

- find all previous names of existing files, then `git log` current + old names (though that could be a lot of arguments), or
- make `git log` ignore commits which refer to deleted (but not renamed) files (this seems unfeasible).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Git does not record renames and copies. It has to use heuristics to identify them. `--follow` will employ these for a single file. `-M` and `-C` are the equivalent for general `git log`.

Comment: I'm not sure how `-M` helps, I've tried it before. `git -C scripts log setup` shows `setup` emerge brand-new, history-less, out of the rename.

Comment: `-C` is for *copies*. You *renamed* everything in `scripts`, `-M`. Try `git log -M`.

Comment: `git -C scripts log setup` means something very different. The `-C` is going to `git` not `git log`. `git -C scripts` means to run `git` as if it was in the `scripts` directory. `git -C scripts log setup` means run `git log setup` as if you were in the scripts directory.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote -C when I actually used -M. Tried again now -- doesn't track across renames, even for a single file. `git log -M -- setup scripts/setup` (i.e. specifying old path as well) OTOH does work.

Comment: [Works For Me™](https://gist.github.com/schwern/acb448cb02ca9b7c037584a82fec60a1). Are you leaving anything out?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at this all wrong, from Git's point of view anyway.  (You could equally say that Git looks at this all wrong—but that's hardcoded into Git and is not going to change!)

In particular, *there is no such thing as file history*, in Git.  History, in Git, is commits.  The commits are the history.  That's all there is.

Git does have, as an option, the ability to *guess* about file renames.  This is useful when you use `git log` with flags and/or arguments that tell it to show something that isn't the actual history, such as: *show me a reduced history that includes only commits in which, from parent to child, the given path-name(s) changed contents*.  This is what `git log -- setup` does: tell `git log` to walk revisions (commits), but only *print* information about a commit where, between parent and child, some `scripts/*` file as been modified.

> Side note: As you mentioned, the `--follow` flag to `git log` only works with a single file name (because the implementation of `--follow` is a horrible hack) and has a bunch of defects.  I believe the `--follow` handling should be completely thrown out and rewritten, but this is a nontrivial undertaking (to put it lightly).  At some point, even if `--follow` isn't completely rewritten, it might start to work for one directory at a time; that point might even have been Git 2.17 or so; I have not tested this, and for this particular case, it wouldn't be the right answer anyway.

The `-M` flag won't really help because it doesn't change the file name(s) that `git log` is using for its restrictions.  Here is the rest of what you need to know.

#### Commits form a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) or DAG

Each commit is numbered, with a hash ID, and each commit stores two things:

- a full snapshot of every file (as of the form it had when the commit was made); and
- metadata: information such as the author and committer, a commit log message, and—crucially for Git itself—the hash IDs of the *parents* of this commit.

The commits themselves form the nodes (or vertices) of a graph, with the hash IDs stored as parent-numbers in each commit forming the links (one-way edges or *arcs*) between these nodes.

This DAG is the generalization of a tree.  A tree data structure would allow for branching:

```
          I--J
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L
```

Here, each uppercase letter stands in for a commit.  Newer commits appear towards the right.  The edges between commits are the one-way (backwards-looking) arcs: from commit `J`, we can work backwards to `I`, and thence to `H` and `G` and so on.  From `L`, we work backwards to `K`, then `H` and so on as before.

Merge commits turn this tree structure into the DAG:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M--N--...
         \    /
          K--L
```

Merge commit `M` points backwards to two commits, so that as Git moves backwards through history, it has to branch: to visit both `L` and `J`, in some order.

When `git log` is run without options, it starts at the current *tip commit* as found by the name `HEAD` and works backwards.  At merges, it follows both branches.  Because it can only actually work on one commit at a time, it handles this using a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

Run `git log` without options or commit-specifying arguments, and this priority queue starts with just one entry for the `HEAD` commit.  The one entry is popped from the queue and the commit is shown.  Then that commit's parent or parents are put into the queue, and we repeat.  As long as each commit visited this way has just one parent, the queue never grows any longer, and the fact that there *is* a queue is invisible.  But when we hit merge commit `M`, *both* parents go into the priority queue.  Now the priority matters: the *next* commit shown is whichever one is at the front of the queue.

The default is to visit in committer-date order, with higher date values (later commits) being higher priority.  So if the committer-date of `L` is higher than that of `J`, we'll see `L` next, and commit `K` will enter the queue.  Otherwise we'll see `J` next, and `I` will enter the queue.  The queue continues to have two entries, so `git log` moves on to the highest priority entry.

#### Branch names

Branch names like `main` or `master` simply gain you (and Git) an entry point into the graph.  Without the names, you would be forced to resort to raw hash IDs, which nobody wants to use.  A branch name is simply a moveable pointer, pointing to some commit node in the graph.  The *names themselves* don't matter: what matters is that each name gives us the hash ID of *one commit*, which lets us find other, earlier commits.

Run with a branch name, `git log` starts from that commit.  Run with more than one branch name, `git log` puts each commit found *via* the branch name into the priority queue, and once again, the priority determines which commit is shown next.

#### How `git log` handles the queue and shows commits

Note that in all cases, `git log` is simply walking the queue, inserting parents as it goes, and showing one commit at a time as it goes.  The default action, with no options, is to show each commit with the `--pretty=medium` format (though this default is adjustable).

We can, however, *restrict* `git log` from showing *all* commits.  We can also alter how it *feeds* the queue and how it *sorts* the queue (i.e., what the relative priorities are).  *Giving a pathname or pathspec argument does both.*  This is important (hence the italics).  The part about which commits get *shown* is easier to describe, because you see its effects immediately.  Before we get into this, though, it's worth a quick side trip through `git diff`.

#### A two-commit diff

Except when we use `git checkout` or `git switch` to extract an entire commit, we're often not really interested in the fact that a commit *is* a full archival snapshot.  We're often more interested in what the *difference* is between two commits.

The `git diff` command can show us that.  For instance, given two commits `E` and `H`, we can run `git diff E H` to see what's different.  Because of Git's internal storage format—files are stored *de-duplicated* as well as compressed and such—Git can very quickly tell that some file in `E` is exactly the same as the file of the same name in `H`, and not bother showing us anything about that file.  For files that *are* different, Git can play a game of [Spot the Difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference) and tell us what *changed*.<sup>1</sup>

If we choose commits that are adjacent—that are parent-and-child, like `G` and `H`—we can see what changed in that one specific commit `H`.  This is particularly useful to humans.  The commit has *all* the changed files (because it has all the files), and the *log message* tells us why the humans who *made* the changes, made them: we can look and see whether the change they made achieve their goal.  That's just one example; there are plenty of examples where this is useful.  The point is that `git diff` can do this pretty easily.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, the output from `git diff` is a *recipe* for changing the left-side file into the right-side file.  It doesn't necessarily reflect *how we made that happen*, just *a way to make it happen*.  This sometimes matters when the change involves bits of syntax, like close-bracket lines, that Git doesn't understand properly.  Git will suggest deleting the wrong bracket, because some *other* bracket seems the same—but sometimes that's not quite right.

---

#### Log, again

When `git log` is working on a normal non-merge commit, it has both the original commit *and* the hash ID of its (single) parent.  This means it can easily run `git diff`.  In fact, finding out if some file(s) have changed is even easier, as we don't need to have Git play spot-the-difference, which is the slow part: we just have Git find out whether there *is* a difference.  So `git log` has this built in.  (It has the full diff built in too, if we want it, but it can do this part *fast*.)

For normal `git log`, this doesn't really matter: it is going to show the commit's metadata, with the appropriate `--pretty` format, no matter what.  But when we run `git log` with path names, what `git log` does is to first *filter out files that aren't listed*—it does this with both this commit and its parent—and then *compare the resulting files*.  If they are all the same, `git log` *simply doesn't print the commit at all*.

What this means is that:

```
git log -- file/in/question.ext
```

only *prints* (with the `--pretty` format) *those commits in which the file in question differs from the copy in its parent*.  **People like to call this "file history", but it's not: it's simply filtered *commit* history.**  Where it falls down—or apart—is precisely where you're into a problem now: what, exactly, does it mean for something to be the *same file* in commits `G` and `H`?

Git does not *store* renames, but it has the ability to *reconstruct* renames on the fly, through its diff engine.  When a left-side commit (`G`) has some file X that does not exist in the right-side (`H`) commit, and the right-side commit has some file Y that does not exist in the left-side commit, Git will, optionally, examine that file-pair to see if the *content* matches or is similar.

Exact matches are very fast to find (due to the de-duplication trick).  "Similar" files are harder and slower.  Using `-M` enables both kinds of rename detection, both in `git diff` *and* in `git log`.  The `--follow` option also enables this rename detection—but it's a horrible hack: when using `--follow`, `git log` has just *one* pathname, and what `--follow` does is to enable `-M` and catch renames and *change the one file name* that it is looking for.  So if `G`-vs-`H` renames the one file, then by the time `git log` is looking at commits `G` and earlier, the one name it is looking for is the old name from `G`, rather than the new name from `H`.

#### Merges: feeding the queue, handling names

A *merge commit* differs from a regular commit in that a merge commit has two (or more, but usually two) parents.  This means we need two diffs.  Git can do this, but there are multiple catches.

First, `git log` normally doesn't bother.  If you're doing a `git log` with no arguments, or even with `-p` turned on to show a diff from parent to child at each commit, when `git log` hits a merge commit, it just throws up its virtual hands and declares this to be too hard.  It prints the log message but doesn't run any diffs at all, and then it adds both (or all) parents to the priority queue as usual.

Second, if you add a pathname or pathspecs, `git log` will do the filtering as usual.  To do that, it strips down both this commit *and all of it parents* to the set of files in your pathspec(s).  It then checks to see whether everything matches in this commit and *any one of the parents*.  If so, it does two things:

- Since there's a match, it follows *just that one parent*.  The theory here goes that you're trying to see why these files look the way they do in the commit you started from—e.g., the `HEAD` commit—and those *other* parents didn't contribute anything, so why bother looking?
- Since that *is* a match, it *does not print this commit*.

So, at merges, we prune off all the branches—or rather, the merge parents, which are branches in the backwards direction that Git uses—that didn't contribute, and then we don't print the merge commit either.  This particular bit of simplification is never directly visible!

If the merge commit's filtered snapshot differs from *every* parent, though, `git log` will (a) print the commit and (b) follow all parents.  We can also force `git log` to follow all parents with `--full-history`, regardless of whether the filtering shows differences.

Note that if we have `--follow` turned on, rename detection can make a mess of this.  Suppose we are at merge `M`, with parents `J` and `L`, and we find that in `M`, file `xyz.ext` is renamed from `abc.ext`.  But it has names in *both* `J` *and* `L`, and one of them is probably still `abc.ext`, while the other is `xyz.ext`.  If we visit both branches, and the rename happens between `I` and `J` before we go on to look at `L` and `K`, we'll be looking for the *wrong name* when we get to the other commits.  (How well or poorly this works, in which cases, depends on a lot of factors.)

We have several extra options here as well:

- `-m` causes `git log` (and `git diff`) to *split* a merge into multiple virtual non-merge commits.  That is, instead of considering commit `M`, our merge, as a single commit with two parents, we have `git log` or `git merge` pretend that there are two commits: `M'` has parent `J`, and `M''` has parent `L`.  These are now normal single-parent commits, which can be displayed using the single-parent displaying methods and diffed using the single-parent diff methods.
- `--first-parent` causes `git log` to *ignore* the extra parents of a merge.  This affects both its diff—`M` will be compared only against `J`, assuming `J` is the *first* parent—and the revision walk: `M` will be treated as a single-parent commit and its (lone) parent will be put on the queue.

Note that the first parent of any merge is the branch you (or whoever) were on when you (or they) *made* the merge.

#### Conclusion

History, in Git, is nothing but the commits, as found by starting from branch names (or other starting points) and working backwards.  Moving files won't avoid "mixing history": it just means that the snapshots in the commits will be different.  The branch names are not the history at all: they're just *entry points into the graph*.

Git does not have true file identity.  It cannot be sure that a file named *X* in commit `A` is the same as, or different from, a file named *X*—or one named *Y*—in commit `H`.  Its *default* assumption is *same-name = same-file*.  This can be adjusted on a diff-by-diff basis.  The tools for this are a bit crude, though.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed write-up -- it needs a detailed read-up (though I know most of the things in principle). Quick note: you seem to imply (?) that having a branch messes things up further. But the scripts branch has full history. Renames were also orchestrated carefully to never change filenames AND content at the same time. Are you saying that deleting the master branch would make it easier to get "human-readable" history on the scripts/ branch, back to big-bang?

Comment: The "avoid mixing separate histories" part does work, at least for future commits. I will be able to see "main" history (without scripts/ changes) by logging the master branch. CI/CD will also not trigger for scripts/ changes. Etc.

Comment: No, having branches isn't bad, it just isn't good either: it's purely neutral.